# Decoding a python function where what's returned is a Iterator[Tuple] -

Tags: python, python-typing

Imagine a function with a signature such as this:

```
def read_something (file_name__path: str) -> Iterator[Tuple[Sequence1, Sequence2]]:
```

If I am writing the function to basically iterate over a document and return a tuple-type object... Does the `Iterator[Tuple[Sequence1, Sequence2]]` portion of the line indicate that because I used the Typing modules, the returned item (if properly constructed) will be an iterator consisting of a tuple?  Or does that mean that I still must iterate over the document and assign each item that I iterate over into an actual tuple (such as tuple(item, item). In other words, does that `Iterator[Tuple[Sequence1, Sequence2]]` magically transform something like two lists into the iterator with the lists becoming a tuple?  Or is that more for the reader of the function to be familiar with the returned object type?

Comment: `->` specifies the type of the function's return value. So it means that it returns an iterator. And when the caller iterates, it gets tuples each time.

Answer (score 0):

1. `->` Do absolutely **nothing**. It only shows that someone who created the function probably planned to set return value as an `Iterator`. Also this return type will be used by IDE when popup hint appear.
2. If you want to check correct typing you may use `mypy`:

```py
from typing import Iterator, Tuple

def correct_iterator() -> Iterator[Tuple[int, str]]:
  for el in [(1, '1'), (2, '2')]:
    yield el

def correct_tuple() -> Tuple[int, str]:
  return (1, '1')

def bad_iterator() -> Iterator[Tuple[int, str]]:
  # that is line 12 ↓
  return (1, '1')
```

```
mypy example.py
```

```
example.py:12: error: Incompatible return value type (got "Tuple[int, str]", expected "Iterator[Tuple[int, str]]")
example.py:12: note: "tuple" is missing following "Iterator" protocol member:
example.py:12: note:     __next__
Found 1 error in 1 file (checked 1 source file)
```

As you can see return value for `bad_iterator` is not `Iterator` and didn't converted into `Iterator`. But type error appeared.

#### Edit: how to check types without mypy

It is able to check returned value type without mypy, but you have to do it outside the defined function:

```py
from typing import Iterator

def the_iterator():
  for el in [1,2,3]:
    yield el

iterator_output = the_iterator()

assert True == isinstance(iterator_output, Iterator)
```

However it is not able to use generics in this check. `isinstance(..., Iterator[int])` will raise error:

```
TypeError: Subscripted generics cannot be used with class and instance checks
```

Comment: Thank you!  Also thanks for the insight on the error detection!

Comment: @ rzlvmp

thank you for the thoughts.  Is it possible to assert that the resulting function's returned data type is the Iterator?  For example - 

`read_ptbtagged("data/PTBSmall/train.tagged")
assert read_ptbtagged ("data/PTBSmall/train.tagged")== Iterator[Tuple[TokenSeq, TagSeq]]`

For me, I just get an assertion error with no specific debug info.

Comment: @Ja4H3ad Yes it is possible. Added info to my answer